# Python - Function array class

Tags: python-3.x

How should I implement the following class?
I want to create class that executes methods in random order when called and after all methods are called once reset array and reshuffle?

```
import random

class RandomFunctions(object):

    def f1():
        print("1")
    def f2():
        print("2")
    def f3():
        print("3")

    f = [f1, f2, f3]

    def __init__(self):
        super(RandomFunctions, self).__init__()
        random.shuffle(self.f)

    def execute(self):
        func = self.f.pop()
        if not self.f:
            reset f
        return func

def main():
    f = RandomFunctions()
    for i in range(6):
        f.execute()()

main()
```

These are the two ideas I came up with, but I'm still wondering what would be the smartest way to implement this sort of class?

```
discard = []
n = 0

    def execute(self):
        func = self.f[self.n]
        self.n += 1
        if self.n == len(self.f):
            self.n = 0
            random.shuffle(self.f)
        return func

    def execute_with_discard(self):
        func = self.f.pop(0)
        discard.append(func)
        if not self.f:
            f = discard[:]
            discard = []
            random.shuffle(self.f)
        return func
```

Comment: Hint: your constructor already contains most of the `reset()` method. Factor it out. Don't forget to refill the depleted list. Module `copy` could help you copy a list, or you could use the `copy_of_list = source_list[:]` idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

class RandomFunctions(object):

    def f1(self):
        print("1")

    def f2(self):
        print("2")

    def f3(self):
        print("3")

    def execute(self):
        if not getattr(self, 'functions', None):
            self.functions = [self.f1, self.f2, self.f3]
            random.shuffle(self.functions)
        return self.functions.pop()


def main():
    f = RandomFunctions()
    for i in range(6):
        f.execute()()


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a class like this? You could use a generator function:

```
def get_random_functions(*functions):
    while True:
        shuffled = list(functions)
        random.shuffle(shuffled)
        while shuffled:
            yield shuffled.pop()

for f in get_random_functions(f1, f2, f3):
    f()
```

Of course, if you prefer your class structure, you can use this by creating the generator in your `__init__` method (`self.gen = get_random_functions(*f)`) and then have your `execute` method return `next(self.gen)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

class RandomFunctions(object):

    def f1():
        print("1")
    def f2():
        print("2")
    def f3():
        print("3")

    f = [f1, f2, f3]

    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def execute(self):
        func = self.f.pop()
        if not self.f:
            self.reset()
        return func()   # execute the function, return the result (if any)

    def reset(self):
        self.f = self.__class__.f[:]    # make copy of class f
        random.shuffle(self.f)

def main():
    f = RandomFunctions()
    for i in range(6):
        f.execute()     # now we only need one pair of parenthesis

main()
```